# Hiding html source code like Facebook or Tidal

Tags: javascript, html

How are new big budget websites hiding their html codes. For ex: if I go to Facebook or Tidal the website ends with `</script>` and not showing rest of HTML code.

What is the trick? Where does the rest of the code go or how they hiding it?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see what and how to ask. HINT: Post effort and code. this question is off topic: _Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it._

Comment: There is no "trick". You can't hide the source code. Some web browsers may not show it only if you go to view source code and only if it's dynamically loaded. The reason for that is, that the browser may show you the source code it had _at load time_, so content added later won't show up. That does not mean the content is "hidden", however - that is definitely not why the website has chosen to do stuff. The HTML is still plainly visible using the developer tools and there is nothing to hide it. It's just a browser decision of what to show you.

Comment: Justinas, sometimes all you need to do is right click over an element and click "Inspect element" - than you'd notice that nothing is hidden.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Source HTML code on Facebook isnt hidden. Is just generated by script. You can view HTML code in developer tools.

[image]